# How to set the position of a Navigation Bar programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationbar

How to set the position of a Navigation Bar programmatically? Autolay have been turned off as its causing issues in other IOS. Cheers guys.

[my layout]

```
View Controller
   View
     Toolbar
     WebView
     Navigation Bar
      Nav Item
   First Responder
   Exit
```

Navigation bar is currently appearing at the bottom of the screen not the top where I want it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

`[self.navigationController.navigationBar setFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)];`

Comment: pretty new tbh what class do I stick that into and how does that link to my nav controller i have in my xib, if theres a way without code that be great also

Comment: by hooking to .h file using IBOutlet.

Comment: totally new to this not sure how to do that

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Interface Builder you can simply drag the navigation bar to where you want it